Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' in path org/hibernate/type/descriptor/converter/spi/EnumValueConverter
I upgraded my spring boot to version '3.2.4' and have hibernate dependency of implementation 'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.5.3', before spring version 3.1.10, it was fine. But after upgrading to 3.2.4. There is error when I started application.
The error message:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$SpringBootBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org/hibernate/type/descriptor/converter/spi/EnumValueConverter
I tried to remove hibernate dependency of io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.5.3 and change to hibernate-63 dependency, none of them help

the error message seems incomplete, is there any more reason / "caused by" part afterwards? org/hibernate/type/descriptor/converter/spi/EnumValueConverter doesn't look like a typical reason for Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' edit: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17241 might be related

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
